# KDE-Plasma : Prevent akonadi stuff from being launched at startup

Tags: kde, startup, plasma

[Akonadi server is well known for being launched with the very first application needing it.](https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi#Disabling_the_Akonadi_subsystem) (Kmail, KaddressBook, KOrganizer…)

Previously running KDE-Plasma-5.**23** with a given set of widgets (including some digital-clock + calendar) the akonadi server would never be launched until I voluntarily launch kmail.

Updating to KDE-Plasma-5.**24** (same set of widgets, same services running) I realize that akonadi server & sons is launched right at DE startup time.

For hundreds of reasons, I just do not want that:

1. Is there somewhere any sort of new tuneable I missed?
2. I realize that some process I had never previously seen is running: `/usr/bin/kalendarac` son of `/usr/bin/plasma_session` Could it be the immediate culprit? Is this the application the digital-clock default widget now relies on ?

   1. Is there a way to tell *kalendarac* not to launch the akonadi server ? (I already tried disabling all sorts of calendar events as part of the widget's settings with no impact noticed on the launch of the akonadi server)
   2. Is there a way to make so this widget behaves just as it used to under KDE-Plasma-5.23 (using akonadi-stuff unaware sources of information)?

Comment: @muru : Rather than feeling just stupid realizing that I had written "*launched at startup*" without immediately having the finger on the solution… I prefer thanking you for having retag-ed my question since it is only when I discovered *startup* as a tag that the path to the solution got brightly illuminated. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrarily to what stated as part of the akonadi page linked in OP, the *digital-clock* widget (whatever its configuration regarding events) holds actually no responsibility in launching the akonadi stuff.

**However, the all brand new (*) `/usr/bin/kalendarac` does.**

Son of `/usr/bin/plasma_session` it is autostarted by default thanks to some dedicated `.desktop` entry in the `/etc/xdg/autostart` directory : `org.kde.kalendarac.desktop`

As usual with xdg services, disabling this system-wide entry (creating an overriding entry containing `Hidden=true`) will efficiently prevent kalendarac from being automatically launched at startup, this incidentally preventing the automatic launch of all the akonadi stuff.

---

(*) First appearance on my system triggered by an upgrade from akonadi-calendar-21. to akonadi-calendar-22. following [KDE Gear 22.04](https://kde.org/announcements/changelogs/gear/22.04.0/)
BTW not immediately related to the KDE-Plasma-5.23 to 5.24 upgrade as I could have suggested in the question.